# How to change programmatically button's width in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have four buttons in a `LinearLayout`.
I want to set the width of these `Button` as 25%.
How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does android:layout\_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write code for this. Just set the `LinearLayout.weight_sum=4`, set each `Button.layout_weight=1` and `width=0dp`

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a Solution**

Set `android:weightSum` to parent layout/view and and set `android:layout_weight` to child layout/view. **Note :** Child layouts/views must be set with width `android:layout_width` 0.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="4"  
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the width at runtime use the below code:

```
button_1=findViewById(R.id.button_1);
button_1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100));
```

Now, if you want to set the width of 4 buttons to 25%, you can pass the weight attribute into `LayoutParams`.

The syntax for runtime equal weight is:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, weight in float);
yourView.setLayoutParams(param);
```

You can use below code to change width of buttons at runtime:

```
Button button1=findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button button3=findViewById(R.id.button3);
Button button4=findViewById(R.id.button4);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);
button1.setLayoutParams(param);
button2.setLayoutParams(param);
button3.setLayoutParams(param);
button4.setLayoutParams(param);
```

I hope it works for you.